# Sharing sites quickly like Laravel valet

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, laravel-valet

I would like to be able to share Laravel application hosted on a local Homestead Vagrant VM to users online.

Is there a way I can easily do this like Valet does? I have too many sites and configurations made to switch over to Valet hence I'm look for a retrofit solution with my existing Homestead setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `vagrant share` 
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/